# How to integrate Firebase authentication service with it's database?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

Let's say i have a scenario where i can use `user.getUid()` to use it as a tag in Firebase Database for every new `user` authenticated. Of course this would bind the database with the current user.

But what if someone gets to know this id, then he can use this id to fetch the data using my Firebase url.

Answer (score 0):

Accessing Firebase can be secured using Firebase Database Rules.
You can allow only the users who are authenticated to access your firebase, 
use :

```
".read": "auth.uid != null"
```

read about Database Rules in Firebase